# Binding Crystal Report with MySQL table or MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, reporting

I have a Crystal report on C# windows application, and MySQL at back-end,
I am able to bind the Crystal report with MySQL Table and MySQL Procedure

My Question here is regarding the performance issue, Which one of above is better approach to bind the crystal reports

NB. In case I am binding with the MySQL Table I need to run some procedure to save the desired data into the MySQL Table and save it before binding it,

Comment: There is no better approach, if you need to run some commands before getting the output, then use an stored procedure, otherwise, use a table or a view.

Comment: I need data on the basis of some user selection, and passing those values as parameter... for the time being this seems as the best possible way to me... looking for other way also.